# SignalR 'Permission denied' in Firefox SDK Addon

Tags: javascript, signalr, firefox-addon-sdk

**Context :** I'm trying to make a Firefox SDK Addon in order to display toast notification when a new message arrives in a TFS Room chat. 
I'm porting [existing code](http://edward.delaporte.us/tfsNotify.html) that works in Google Chrome.

**Code extract :**

index.js

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.tfsservername",
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.min.js"), self.data.url("notifications.js")]
});
```

data/notifications.js

```
$(function() { 
    // [...] checking notifications permissions here

    // Suscribing to new messages
    unsafeWindow.$.connection.chatHub.on('messageReceived', function() {/*showing notification here*/});
});
```

**Issue :**
The `$.connection.chatHub.on(...)` raises the error **`Permission denied to access property Symbol.toPrimitive`** in the file `tfs/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js`.

The same line of code (without `unsafeWindow`) executed with the javascript console **actually works** so I'm guessing it might be due to the addon code being executed separatedly from the page code but have no idea as to how to fix this or if it *is* the actual origin of the problem.

Comment: I think you would have to export your listener function to the unsafeWindow in order for the unsafeWindow to add that listener. But I'm not sure that's the problem here. For more details about that, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts

Comment: @humanoid thank you, that did the trick ! If you would turn your comment into an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.